# What is best practice for TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If have some troble, i have array with function, like:

```
this._array = [handler, func, type]
```

How i need declare this private Property:

```
 1. Array<any>
 2. any[]
 3. T[]
 4. Array<T>
```

What difference in this declaration?

And some question:

```
this._array.push(()=>{ console.log("hey")})
```

How i can define type function?

Comment: What are the types of `handler`, `func` and `type`?

Comment: @Paleo I dont know type but add to array:  this._array.push(()=>{ console.log("hey")})

Comment: So, the type of this element (named `func`?) is: `() => void`. What are the types of the two others?

Comment: @Paleo all this element are void

Comment: You ask for best practices in TypeScript. But generic types like `any[]` are not "best practices" for a TypeScript developper. Elements in your array cannot be of type "void", it is a nonsense. The code `() => void` is not a type `void`, it is the type of: _"a function with no parameter and no return value"_. Now if you don't know what is a _type_ in TypeScript, I suggest to just post here the code where you fill the elements in `this._array`, then we should be able to deduce the types you use.

Answer (score 2):

In you case if you don't know which types can be in your array use `any[]`, which is not desired. I suggest you to refactor your code to have arrays with the same types.

**1)** `Array<any>` - accept anything.

**2)** `any[]` - is the same as above one.

```js
console.log([].constructor);
console.log((new Array()).constructor);
```

**3)** `T[]` contains only elements which type is `T`. Can be used in [**Generic**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

**4)** `Array<T>` same as the above.

Saying you have a class

```
class SomeClass<T> {
   items: Array<T>;
}

const numbers = new SomeClass<number>();
const strings = new SomeClass<string>();
```

For numbers the items will be of type `number[]`, for strings it will be `string[]`. The type which will replace `T` is got from the `<T>` in the object creation statement.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript, like JavaScript, allows you to work with arrays of values. Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use the type of the elements followed by `[]` to denote an array of that element type:

```
let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

The second way uses a generic array type, `Array<elemType>:`

```
let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

More refer here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `Array<any>` and `any[]` are equivalent and are arrays of anything (not type checking on items, best avoid these if you can help it)
2. `T[]` and `Array<T>` are equivalent and are arrays of the given type `T`, so you will get compile type checking for these.

If you need to store something like `[handler, func, type]` :

```
   let arrary: Array<(param:number) => void> = []
```

With this version the items pushed are checked to conform to your handler signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [tuple](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) instead of an array, eg.:

```
private _array: [any, () => void, string];
```